# Dbus not starting on Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, d-bus, touch, unity

```
systemctl --user start dbus

Failed to start dbus.service: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
See user logs and 'systemctl --user status dbus.service' for details.

systemctl --user status dbus.service

Failed to get properties: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
```

Log messages: see attachment

[image]
[image]

```
echo XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
```

returns /run/user/32011

```
id -u
```

returns 32011

The `dbus-user-session` package is installed.

How do I get to run dbus.service? It's needed for an application to run that is written in go.